# Warning when using sizeof for array subscript

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

Today I decided to compile my code with gcc -W -Wall and it's giving me a warning I just can't solve.

I was trying to reduce the amount of #defines i've been using, and thought sizeof() would be the answer. Everything else seems to be okay, only this one warning, but it's got me quite foxed:

```
if (1)    // set random id string for this session
    {
    register unsigned int count, until=sizeof(session.id);
    for (count=0;count<until;count++)
        {   session.id[count]=randchar();   }
    session.id[count]=0;
    }
```

The compiler is giving me this warning:

```
warning: array subscript is above array bounds
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: -1 for misleading me by the ugly formatting & indentation.

Comment: Pretty harsh to -1 for using Whitesmiths (not that I like Whitesmiths).

Comment: @MichaelBurr It's an insane formatting style, if this is at all a formatting style. It just made me write an incorrect answer. Harsh? Then what'd you call doing what OP did?

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I didn't use to use squigglies for one-liners, but someone told me this was bad practice, and I believed them because i've known some compilers (at least, borland turbo C) make mistakes that way. This way ambiguity is removed, without requiring 3 lines instead of 1, although I do take your point.

Comment: Without the struct (or union) definition for session it is impossible to answer this question. The final `session.id[count]=0;` is always wrong, the assignment inside the loop would be wrong if `session.id` is not a character or character array.

Answer (score 4):

your error because of this :

```
session.id[count]=0;
```

change to this :

```
session.id[count - 1]=0;
```

Comment: @AndreyT Oh well, yes! Screw bad formatting. **Seriously.**

Answer (score 0):

The

```
until=sizeof(session.id);
```

assigns `until` to the size (in bytes) of the array.  This works for `char' element types, but will cause overflows for larger datatypes.  You probably want something like

```
until = sizeof(session.id) / sizeof(session.id[0])
```